# Print version of a module without importing the entire package

Tags: python, import, module, version, package

Is it possible to check the version of a package if only a module is imported?

When a package is imported like...

```
import pandas as pd
```

I use:

```
print('pandas : version {}'.format(pd.__version__))
```

to print the version number.

How do I check the version number if only a module is imported, like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

print (sys.modules[plt.__package__].__version__)
```

if you import just a function:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as function
import sys

try:module_name = function.__module__[:function.__module__.index(".")]
except:module_name = function.__module__

print (sys.modules[module_name].__version__)
```

and if this doesn't work you could just import pip and `for` loop all the modules.

Comment: Thanks! And how do I check the version numer of sklearn when I use "from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix".

Comment: Note that this answer is equivalent to directly importing the top-level package: Simply `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` is semantically equivalent, while being more readable. I see that this post answers how to derive the package version when importing only a subpackage. But the question in the title suggest that one can somehow avoid extra overhead, which is not the case. (I you doubt my reasoning, compare `dir(sys.module["matplotlib"])` and `import matplotlib; dir(matplotlib)`, they're identical)